# Visual Studio 2019 and OpenCV 4 compile programms for Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, winapi, visual-c++

Is it possible to compile programs for Windows 7 or Windows XP in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10?
I have installed Windows 8.1 SDK but it didn't help me. An .exe file doesn't run on windows 7.
What do I need to do to run my program on Windows 7? Adding this rows in my main.cpp also didn't help me.

```
#include <winsdkver.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <sdkddkver.h>
```

Platform tools:
[image]

Addititional include directories:

[image: Addititional include directories]

The application error:

[image]

Comment: i doubt it - windows xp is long out of support.

Comment: Unless you are using API implemented only in Windows 8 or 10 it should work on Windows 7. For projects compiled with DLL based runtime library, install appropriate runtime on target device. You can support Windows XP by selecting v141_xp platform toolset. Reported error may suggest missing COM initialization `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because messages are not in english

Comment: Simon, I can remove images from the question, the meaning of the question will not change. I have Visual Stduio 2019 on Windows 10 and a program that doesn't use the Windows API. What should I install or specify in the project settings to run the .exe file on Windows 7?

Comment: Daniel, I've installed vs redistributable on Windows 7, but it didn't help me ((

Comment: Have you tried calling `CoInitialize`, `CoInitializeEx` or `OleInitialize` as a first statement in `WinMain`?

Comment: Daniel, my program is console application that uses only functions from std and opencv, it doesn't use functions from windows sdk. It seems my program should work without CoInitialize, CoInitializeEx or OleInitialize.

Comment: Install WinDbg/Debugging Tools for Windows on Windows 7 box and see where is problem. [https://superuser.com/questions/982644/where-can-i-get-windbg-for-windows-7-64bit-without-the-whole-sdk](https://superuser.com/questions/982644/where-can-i-get-windbg-for-windows-7-64bit-without-the-whole-sdk)

Comment: Daniel, thank you, I'll try. Partly I solved my problem by manual compiling OpenCV for x86 platform with disabled SSE instructions. And now my program works on Win7 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0xC000001D: Illegal instruction, which was related to the SSE instruction used in the code. Some new SSE instruction are not implemented at some different CPU.

I suggest you could try to use [/arch:IA32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x86?view=msvc-160) in MSVC compiler options to disable modern CPU instructions.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help me, thank you

Comment: Maybe opencv was compiled with SSE...

Comment: I've compiled OpenCV for x86 platform and now my program works on Windows 7, thank you a lot for the answer :)